# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

Freelancing's [4th moderator election](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/election/4) has come to a close. Since there were not enough candidates for a competitive election, we simply appointed the candidates who nominated:

[image: morsor] [image: Magus]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), Canadian Luke, shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

The Community Team is very happy that this election had a successful outcome, even if it didn't make it to the voting phase. Thanks to everyone who participated!

Comment: Magus no longer a moderator. Seems to have stopped visiting the site entirely

Answer (score 6):

Congratulations, you two!

My nomination was withdrawn as the Community Team discovered that there was some targeted voting (unsolicited by me) on my posts, which resulted in a series of voting reversals that placed me below the required reputation threshold to nominate. This caused the number candidates to drop below the required 3 for an election to occur.

This doesn't matter to me, though. The point of this election was to get some Freelancing.SE-oriented users who are willing to do the thankless job of getting this site back in motion. You both now have that very difficult job, and you have my highest blessings as you move forward with that!

Don't worry, though, I don't plan on going anywhere. I'll still be around to help out in whatever capacity I can.

Good luck!

Comment: whaaaat, that is some house of cards stuff

Comment: It's a bit of a shame, yeah. I think the worst of it was that this came to me 15 minutes before nominations closed, so I didn't quite have time to gather the remaining rep required before the election was over. But, oh well. I do hope y'all serve the site well!

Comment: It is for sure, and you're at 294, I'd have certainly given you a vote

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to the moderation team, morsor and Magus! Thank you for stepping up and helping!

I do not plan on going anywhere, especially now that I know I have some backup when it comes to moderation!

Thanks for your help JNat with running yet another election, and for advertising the position for all to see.