# Freelancing is graduating in December 16

Tags: discussion, site-topic, election

This is just in, Freelancing is graduating Stack Exchange to become an official fully grown site.

Congratulations to all of you! :D

What changes?

- No more beta label
- Official announcement

> We are planning for sites that are leaving Beta to lose that label on December 16th. We will be announcing this on Meta Stack Exchange. It will be similar to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331708/congratulations-to-our-29-oldest-beta-sites-theyre-now-no-longer-beta) that we made in 2019 when a number of sites exited Beta at that time.

- There will be some customization in the future, but not by the graduation date
- Reputation points will remain

> Currently, site design customization will not be part of the graduation process. We’re hoping that some lightweight customization for sites will be available in the future, but we don’t have a timeline for that right now. You will also retain your beta reputation levels.

- New elections by 2022/2023

> Since we have a large number of sites leaving Beta, we will be scheduling these elections throughout 2022 and possibly even into 2023. We’ll be in touch with your team in the future when we are ready to schedule your graduation election.

And here's why we're graduating :D

> We have been reviewing all of the sites that are currently in Beta to determine which sites are ready to lose that label and join other graduated sites on the Stack Exchange Network. Based on the longevity of your site, the number of open questions, and the number of open questions that have at least one upvoted answer, Freelancing Stack Exchange is ready to leave Beta.

Comment: Put on your graduation caps!

Comment: Read the fine print: > Re: Beta Sites: "Unlike most elections, we won't require pro tempore elections to be competitive. If the number of nominees is less than or equal to the number of open slots, we'll end the election before the voting stage.". Source: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314459/282094 - For a graduate site the next election **requires** ***4*** candidates minimum.

Comment: ahh but that only impacts elections, nobody cares about mods hahaha

Comment: ... and if the election fails ... back to where we were last week.

Comment: is that so? where did you read that part?

Comment: Probably [the](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331708/congratulations-to-our-29-oldest-beta-sites-theyre-now-no-longer-beta#comment1082247_331760) same [place](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331708/congratulations-to-our-29-oldest-beta-sites-theyre-now-no-longer-beta#comment1083661_331760) you sourced your upvoted comment [from](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/323901/what-happens-if-there-are-no-candidates-in-an-election/323902#comment1059283_323902).

Comment: I didn't source it from there, and I didn't find the failed election section. Not sure if you read it somewhere else or mixed up the information. It seems that a failed election wouldn't cause the site to be back at the beta status.

Comment: That's not what I'm saying, that's not what it says. If you have an *idea* provide your source (instead of asking for mine), if you have an election related question applicable to all sites you can ask on the main meta. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6wSe.png) is shown to people when they reply, you should be receptive of the expert advice we can offer at MSE.

Comment: I might have misunderstood something and I choose to bail on this conversation. If I sounded rude or angry, I'm sorry, not my intention at all. I was trying to understand what the advice was, not contesting it.

Answer (score 3):

This is such good news!

I'm surprised though, many of us were concerned that Freelancing might not even be kept in Public Beta anymore, due to the lack of interest in Mod elections. Would you be able to share with us the reason that was given for graduating? We learned that [Quantum Computing had sufficient visits and other metrics](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/517/2293).

Comment: yup! just updated the question with the reason, basically, we are active enough to go live

Answer (score 1):

This is especially nice news! Nice to hear about the positive turnaround for this site's lifecycle.

Just two weeks prior to this announcement, this site was facing the prospect of getting shut down as no one was willing to step up and moderate the site. It's all thanks to [you and morsor](https://freelancing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/2021-community-moderator-election-results) that this site continues to exist in the first place, and now it's nice to hear that the site is on its way to becoming a full-fledged member of the network. I hope this site continues to supply live, easily-accessible knowledge to others for years to come.